# How to access dynamically created tablewidget?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget

in my project I create three items : QCombobox,QLabel,QCheckbox from a database for every productname (which give name of itself to QLabel as text). After that I list those items in a QTableWidget. The thing I want to do is reaching selected QCheckbox's row's QLabel's text and current index of same row's QCombobox.

I can reach the selected QCheckboxs of QTableWidget but for further I don't know how to reach other items of QCheckbox's row.

**The function is current_index which should return QLabel's text and QCheckbox's text.**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui,QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel,QMainWindow,QApplication,QHeaderView,QTableWidgetItem,QMessageBox,QWidget
from uretim_sayfasi import Ui_MainWindow
import mysql.connector
global curs
global conn

conn=mysql.connector.connect(
    host="*****",
    user="****",
    password="*****",
    database="****"
    )
curs=conn.cursor()

class my_app(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(my_app, self).__init__()
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.list_products()
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.current_index)

    def list_products(self):
        curs.execute("SELECT productName,productId FROM products_list")
        products=curs.fetchall()
        curs.execute("SELECT shipmentTime FROM shipmentTime ORDER BY id")
        shipmentTime=curs.fetchall()
        c=0
        for i in products:
            self.ui.productlist.setRowCount(int(c + 1))
            self.ui.productlist.setColumnCount(3)
            e=QtWidgets.QLabel()
            e.setText(i[0])
            self.combo=QtWidgets.QComboBox()
            self.combo.addItems(j[0] for j in shipmentTime)
            self.checkbox=QtWidgets.QCheckBox(i[1])
            self.checkbox.setObjectName(i[1])
            self.ui.productlist.setCellWidget(c,2,self.combo)
            self.ui.productlist.setCellWidget(c,0,self.checkbox)
            self.ui.productlist.setCellWidget(c,1,e)

            c+=1


    def current_index(self):
        items=self.ui.productlist.findChildren(QtWidgets.QCheckBox)
        for i in items:
            if i.isChecked():
                n=i.objectName()
                print(n)

def app():
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=my_app()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

app()
```

[the result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Nro.png)
In my senario, when pushbutton clicked, it should return selected QCheckbox's (ARG.YI.2002 and ARG.YI.2021) QLabel's text **("KREMA" for ARG.YI.2002 and "CEVİZİÇİ EXTRA" for ARG.YI.2021) ** and QCombobox's currenttext  **("5 GÜN" for ARG.YI.2002 and "1 GÜN" for ARG.YI.2021)**.

Comment: Can you better explain what you want to get from `current_index`? Consider that the concept of "current index" is *not* the index of a checked item, and with your function you'll also get *any* checked QCheckBox.

Comment: Actually, I want to get QLabel's text and QCombobox's text according to checked QCheckbox's row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a *list* for the widgets, and populate it with each row of widgets added as a tuple.

Note that I slightly changed the `for` cycle to make it more readable, and I also moved the `setRowCount()` and `setColumnCount()` outside it, as continuously setting them in the cycle with the same values is useless.

I also changed the widget references, which are now local variables and not instance attribute anymore: when using loops it doesn't make a lot of sense to overwrite an instance attribute for every cycle, as it will always be lost on the next iteration.

```
class my_app(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(my_app, self).__init__()
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.list_products()
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.current_index)

        self.widgetList = []

    def list_products(self): 
        self.widgetList.clear()

        curs.execute("SELECT productName,productId FROM products_list")
        products=curs.fetchall()
        curs.execute("SELECT shipmentTime FROM shipmentTime ORDER BY id")
        shipmentTime=curs.fetchall()

        self.ui.productlist.setRowCount(len(products))
        self.ui.productlist.setColumnCount(3)

        for row, i in enumerate(products):
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(i[0])
            combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
            combo.addItems(j[0] for j in shipmentTime)
            checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(i[1])
            checkbox.setObjectName(i[1])
            self.ui.productlist.setCellWidget(row, 0, checkbox)
            self.ui.productlist.setCellWidget(row, 1, label)
            self.ui.productlist.setCellWidget(row, 2, combo)

            self.widgetList.append((checkbox, label, combo))

    def current_index(self):
        for checkbox, label, combo in self.widgetList:
            if checkbox.isChecked():
                print(checkbox.objectName(), label.text(), combo.currentText())
```

Do note that the above is the most basic (and probably more pythonic) possibility; you can do the same without the list and using the functions provided by QTableWidget, which is more "Qt-onic" ;-) :

```
    def current_index(self):
        for row in range(self.ui.productlist.rowCount()):
            checkbox = self.ui.productlist.cellWidget(row, 0)
            if isinstance(QtWidgets.QCheckBox) and checkbox.isChecked():
                label = self.ui.productlist.cellWidget(row, 1)
                combo = self.ui.productlist.cellWidget(row, 2)
                print(checkbox.objectName(), label.text(), combo.currentText())
```

Comment: I am very thankful for this solution. I was obsessed with getting those texts from tablewidget and I couldn't think getting them with a different method. It works smoothly.

Comment: @MelikşahÖztürk you can anyway, there's no need to use `findChildren`: as with almost any function that begins with `set*` in Qt, there is probably a "getter" that returns the current state/object/value set: in this case, [`cellWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#cellWidget). See the update.

Comment: the edit is more delightful to run and as you said it is more Qt-onic and more what I looked for :) thank you again.